# How to use anchorScroll() with in ng-repeat to have start view at index x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, anchor-scroll

I am trying to list all minutes in 24 hours duration with a step of 15 minutes.
So, I have these minutes lists in array and looping them using `ng-repeat`.
In my case, when page is loaded I would like to show list from 07:30 as top, but if I scroll up it must be able to show 07:15, 07:00...

I tried to use `filter: 'after'`, it shows from 07:30 but not before 07:15, 07:00...

Is there a way the `ng-repeat` starts showing from element 07:30?

[I have created a plunker with what I have tried.](http://plnkr.co/edit/lIwbi94KKhjSYk9GK9WS?p=preview)

Any help please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CQeaComH4xv2h2ckBudA?p=preview)

```
  $scope.goto = function (){
    $timeout(function() {
            $location.hash(30);
            $anchorScroll();
        });
  }
```

Use $timeout :-)